# Changing locale in MainActivity works, but changing it in Fragment gives Nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, locale

I have a `ListPreference` which I want to use to change the language of my app.

```
    <ListPreference
        android:key="@string/language_preference"
        android:title="@string/preference_title"
        android:entries="@array/language_array"
        android:entryValues="@array/language_data"
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false" />
```

I'm using [this](https://github.com/akexorcist/Localization) localization library to help. In my `MainActivity` I have two functions to change the (currently) two supported languages:

```
    fun changeLanguageGer() {
        setLanguage("de")
    }

    fun changeLanguageEn() {
        setLanguage("en")
    }
```

I happen to have a spinner in my `MainActivity` that I "misused" to check if those methods work: When changing to the according spinner item my app language changes as expected.

But I actually want to make this change in my settings with the `ListPreference`.

In the `SettingsFragment` I have the following code:

```
class SettingsActivity : LocalizationActivity() {

    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
            ...

            // language
            val listPreference =
                findPreference<Preference>(getString(R.string.language_preference)) as ListPreference?
            listPreference?.setOnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
                if (preference is ListPreference) {
                    val index = preference.findIndexOfValue(newValue.toString())
                    val locale = preference.entryValues[index]
                    if (locale == "de") {
                        Toast.makeText(activity,locale, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        MainActivity().changeLanguageGer()
                    }
                    if (locale == "en") {
                        Toast.makeText(activity,locale, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        MainActivity().changeLanguageEn()
                    }
                }
                true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the following Nullpointerexception: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference`. I added the toast statements to make sure the output I get when clicking on the language I want to change to is correct, which it is (either gives me "de" or "en").

How would I go about debugging this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I do generally know what a Nullpointerexception is, but I don't know where it is coming from in this case and how I could fix it

Comment: the error log tells you that you are calling `getSharedPreferences()` method on a null reference which is context. make sure you invoke that method when you have context. you have to read about the activity lifecycle and Do Not make an instance of activity like you did for `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(activity as SettingsActivity).changeLanguageEn()
```

Try using this to change the language.

Comment: This results in `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.tuner.SettingsActivity cannot be cast to com.example.tuner.MainActivity` - I probably should have specified that the `SettingsFragment` is inside a `SettingsActivity`, will edit my post

Comment: Thanks a lot, when putting my two methods for changing the languages into the `SettingsActivity` instead and calling it like that it works!